# Need to add same properties in two different classes

Tags: c#

I have two classes like Class A and Class B. Class A have some properties, methods and Class B have only the properties. But both Classes have the same set of properties.

My Question is, If I add any new property in Class A, I need to add that in Class B also. If I did not add means, need to show error. How can I achieve this through C#?

Comment: Are you in need of a base Class with given properties that A and B should both inherit?

Comment: if class b will always have the same properties as class a, simply inherit. but then again, why are they two different classes?

Comment: Each of the `C#-?.0` tags descriptions include the phrase *"Use this tag if your question specifically pertains to C# ?.0 specific features."* So by definition, at most, only one of those 3 can apply. Please [edit] your question to remove the ones which do not apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may achieve this by using an Interface and implementing it both in class A and class B. In the interface, define the property that is required in class A and B:

```
public interface ICommonProperty
{
   string MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would say it depends on what he wants to do with those properties. If he wants to abstractly call those properties, but they never work the same, then your solution with an interface works. If those properties will function the exact same, then an abstract base class, as per @ThierryV 's solution is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my case is slightly different with abstract and interface. In abstract or interface case we need to add a new property in their own base class. In my case, if I add a new property in Class A(Not an abstract and interface ), we have to implement(declare) that property in Class B also

Comment: Can you inherit from Class A in Class B?

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) `abstract` to create a class in common for A and B.

```
abstract class BaseClass   // Abstract class
{
    public int X {get;set;} // property in common for 2 class
}

class A : BaseClass
{
}

class B : BaseClass
{
    public int Y {get;set;} // other property of B
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my case is slightly different with abstract and interface. In abstract or interface case we need to add a new property in their own base class. In my case, if I add a new property in Class A(Not an abstract and interface ), we have to implement(declare) that property in Class B also.

Comment: You'd only need to put the common properties in the abstract class. That way each derivative of the base class can still be its own interpretation, and you prevent repeating yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the abstract class. The abstract keyword enables you to create classes and class members that are incomplete and must be implemented in a derived class.

Here is a simple example related to your question However you can understand and learn about Abstract classes here : [Abstract Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/abstract-and-sealed-classes-and-class-members)

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A objA = new A();
        objA.printA();
        B objB = new B();
        objB.printB();

    }
}

abstract class Parent{

    public int a = 5;

}

class A : Parent
{
    public void printA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In class A, value is "+a);
    }
}

class B : Parent
{
    public void printB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In class B, value is "+a);
    }
}
```

Output of the above program is:

```
In class A, vlaue is 5
In class B, vlaue is 5
```

Hope this helps you.